# Twitter Share autofill

Tags: javascript, html, twitter, share-button

I am trying to get a tweet button that shares customized text.  The problem is that text is randomized. i.e. I have a random quote generator but I want to share the quote that is being displayed at that time so to my knowledge.

```
<a class="twitter-share-button" href="https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=Hello%20world>Tweet</a>
```

Won't work because I don't know what the text will be at any given time.

The Javascript is an Array called 'quotes' of quotes pushed through.

```
function cycle() {
    var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * (quote.length));
    document.getElementByID('getit').innerHTML = quote[randomNumber];
}
```

and in HTML I have a button that cycles through the loop like so.

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary onclick="cycle()">Get New Quote</button>
```

So, any ideas as to how this can be done?